# Are molecules exchanged between a solid and liquid in equlibrium?

Tags: phase, vapor-pressure

In [Vapor-Liquid Equilibrium](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/10%3A_Solids_Liquids_and_Solutions/10.11%3A_Vapor-Liquid_Equilibrium), it is my understanding that molecules exchange between the gas and liquid continuously; even when no difference in temperature or [partial pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure) exists.

[image]

Regarding [Solid-Liquid Equilibrium](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/DeVoes_Thermodynamics_and_Chemistry/12%3A_Equilibrium_Conditions_in_Multicomponent_Systems/12.05%3A_Solid-Liquid_Equilibria); is there a similar **continuous** exchange of molecules? For example on a single crystal of ice submerged in pure water at perfect and constant 0°C, will molecules on the surface of this crystal exchange with the liquid? In the past I have assumed this to be the case, but now realize I have not seen a reference that explicitly details this like is common for vapor-liquid equilibrium. Are there any references that calculate the rate at which this occurs? Side question, is there also a continuous exchange for solid-gas equilibrium?

Comment: Yes, and yes. All solids have some vapor pressure, and (often negligible) solubility.

Comment: Generally, molecules/atoms/ions have no means for awareness the system is in equilibrium, being "instructed to do nothing". Additionally, they do not have temperature. A single kinetic energy value belongs to a wide range of possible system temperatures, so they are changing a phase at will.

Comment: Your question was already answered https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73344/proof-of-dynamic-nature-of-equilibrium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of Dynamic Nature of Equilibrium](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73344/proof-of-dynamic-nature-of-equilibrium)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even two **solids** in contact may exchange atoms, such as [gold in contact with lead](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF03215091.pdf). Accidental [cold-welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding) is a serious problem in space technology, in particular.

You can prove to yourself that ice/water, in equilibrium, exchanges molecules: immerse an ice-cube on a string in water at 0°C, and the cube will *slowly* change shape. "No chemist ever observes the same ice cube twice..." as Heraclitus or Heisenberg stated (I'm not certain).